# Add different widgets in column conditionally

Tags: flutter

I need to build the respective widgets only for the items that are selected from dialog. I am getting the list of items that are selected from the dialog. I need to display the only respective widget if its matches the name. I am only getting the widget from index 0 i.e **गाई** . I have tried as follows:

I am getting the list of checked value from dialog as follows:

```
onChecked(var value, int i, String name) {
setState(() {
  if (responseData[i].isChecked == true) {
    checkIndex.add(i);
    nonRepated.add(responseData[i].name);             
  } else {
    nonRepated.remove(responseData[i].name);       
  }
});  
}
```

BuildLayout

```
Widget _buildLayout(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      for (int i = 0; i < nonRepated.length; i++)
        nonRepated[i] == "गाई"
            ? Cow(nonRepated, i, checkIndex[i], responseData[i].name,
                onDelete)
            : nonRepated[i] == "भेँडा/बाख्रा/च्याङ्ग्रा"
                ? SheepGoat(nonRepated, i, checkIndex[i],
                    responseData[i].name, onDelete)
                : Text(i.toString()),
      SizedBox(
        height: 10,
      ),
      nonRepated.length != 0 ? _buildButton() : Container(),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child: Column(
          // item.value is  nonRepated[i] and item.key is i
          children: nonRepated.asMap().entries.map((item) => item.value == 
          "गाई"
              ? Cow(nonRepated, item.key, checkIndex[item.key], 
           responseData[item.key].name,
              onDelete)
              : item.value == "भेँडा/बाख्रा/च्याङ्ग्रा"
              ? SheepGoat(nonRepated, item.key, checkIndex[item.key],
              responseData[item.key].name, onDelete)
              : Text(item.key.toString())).toList(),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 10,
      ),
      nonRepated.length != 0 ? _buildButton() : Container(),
    ],
  ),
)
```